# Angular 16 - custom style palette takes no effect on material components

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular16

I am currently experimenting with custom color themes for my angular application. But unfortunately I can't find any conclusive documentation on how to integrate them correctly into my app.
Unfortunately the documentation of Angular Material [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) is also quite inconclusive for me. I tried to follow it as good as i can, but somehow it doesn't take any effect on my material components ...

The primary color i defined should be red:

[image]

But the colors shown on for example the datepicker is still purple:

[image]

My datepicker component html:

```html
<div class="test">
    <input class="input-date" 
    [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</div>
```

Thats how my `theme.scss` looks like:

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

$dark-primary-text: rgba(black, 0.87);
$light-primary-text: white;

$test-palette: (
    50: #F5E3E3,
    100: #E6BABA,
    200: #D58C8C,
    300: #C45D5D,
    400: #B83B3B,
    500: #AB1818,
    600: #A41515,
    700: #9A1111,
    800: #910E0E,
    900: #800808,
    A100: #FFAFAF,
    A200: #FF7C7C,
    A400: #FF4949,
    A700: #FF3030,
    contrast: (
        50: $dark-primary-text,
        100: $dark-primary-text,
        200: $dark-primary-text,
        300: $dark-primary-text,
        400: $dark-primary-text,
        500: $light-primary-text,
        600: $light-primary-text,
        700: $light-primary-text,
        800: $light-primary-text,
        900: $light-primary-text,
        A100: $dark-primary-text,
        A200: $dark-primary-text,
        A400: $dark-primary-text,
        A700: $light-primary-text,
    )
);

$custom-primary: mat.define-palette($test-palette);
$custom-accent: mat.define-palette($test-palette);

$custom-app-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
    color:(
        primary: $custom-primary,
        accent: $custom-accent,
    )
));

@include mat.all-component-themes($custom-app-theme);
```

And im trying to inject it here in my `angular.json`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "cli": {
    "cache": {
      "enabled": false,
      "path": ".cache",
      "environment": "all"
    },
    "analytics": false
  },
  "projects": {
    "deployConfig": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": { "@schematics/angular:component": { "style": "scss" } },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/MyAppWeb/static",
            "deployUrl": "static/",
            "index": {
              "input": "src/index.html",
              "output": "../index.html"
            },
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src/favicon.ico",
                "output": "./../"
              },
              {
                "glob": "my-service-worker.js",
                "input": "src/my-service-worker.js",
                "output": "./../"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "./../assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "bootstrap-icons.svg",
                "input": "./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../../MyAppwebconfig",
                "output": "./assets/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/theme.scss", <-- here
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "./node_modules/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css",
              "./node_modules/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-multiple.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-clip-rotate-multiple.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js",
              "src/assets/js/notification.js"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": true,
            "namedChunks": true,
            "webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,

              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "8mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "15kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "budgets": []
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "disableHostCheck": true,
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyAppWeb:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyAppWeb:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "MyAppWeb:build:development"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyAppWeb:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "./assets/images/MyApp_Logo_Framed.svg",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/theme.scss", <-- here
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MyAppWeb:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "MyAppWeb:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MyAppWeb": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/MyAppWeb",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "bootstrap-icons.svg",
                "input": "./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/my-service-worker.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/theme.scss", <-- here
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "./node_modules/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css",
              "./node_modules/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-multiple.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-clip-rotate-multiple.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js",
              "src/assets/js/notification.js"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "sourceMap": false,
            "optimization": true,
            "namedChunks": true,
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json",
            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "6mb",
                  "maximumError": "8mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "15kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyAppWeb:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyAppWeb:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "MyAppWeb:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyAppWeb:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "./assets/images/MyApp_Logo_Framed.svg",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/theme.scss", <-- here
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MyAppWeb:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "MyAppWeb:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not even sure where to inject this exactly, I just added it to all styles sections. I marked it with `<-- here`.

Can anyone here help me with how to properly integrate this into an Angular 16 application? What am I missing?

Thanks for any help!